# Can the order in which "Optional Updates" are installed cause problems in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, updates, intel

I always install the latest updates on my Windows 11 computer via Windows Updates. Today I decided to install these 3 OPTIONAL UPDATES (via Windows Updates):

INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4 Intel Corporation

Display - 30.0.100.9805

Intel Corporation - Extension - 8/27/2018 12:00:00 AM - 24.20.100.6291

These 3 optional updates had been available for a long time, but I hadn't installed them yet. The "Intel Corporation - Display" and "Intel Corporation - Extension" updates were installed correctly, but the "INTEL - System" update was not possible to install (0x8024200b error), then I clicked on "Try again" and this update was installed correctly as well.

Today I read that the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update caused performance issues on Windows 10/11 computers. That's why I'd like to know:

1. Has the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update caused performance issues on your Windows 10/11 computer?
2. If the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update has cuased issues on your computer, is it possible to uninstall it?
3. I already had these optional updates installed:

Intel Corporation - Display - 31.0.101.2111

Intel - SoftwareComponent - 2130.1.15.0

Intel Corporation - Display - 30.0.101.1340

INTEL - System - 10.1.14.8

Can the 3 optional updates I installed today cause driver conflicts or other problems? (I'm asking because the "INTEL - System - **10.1.14.8**" update that I already had looks newer than the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - **10.1.11.4**")

Comment: I usually keep my optional updates current to prevent as much of this as possible. Normally on my machines an earlier driver update will stop and say later driver is there, do you wish to continue?

Comment: Is the year of those updates 1968?  If so, what's up with that?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It has happened that it "updated" my network driver, to a network driver that didn't work.

I unrolled and tried again a later, same issue.

Whatever the problem was, it got fixed, because 2 months later the same update worked.

If you don't want potentially breaking updates, make sure you're not on the "Windows Insider Program". Its the last option on the Windows Update screen.

Answer (score -1):

I understand. Thank you guys for letting me know. My computer is working fine. I just wanted to confirm with you guys if the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update had caused any issues on your Windows 10/11 computers as some articles said (by the way, you can see the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update history **[here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=%22INTEL%20-%20System%20-%207%2F18%2F1968%22)**).

I was also concerned because the "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" update had been available for a long time (released 1 ~ 2 years ago), but I had not installed it yet, and I was afraid that it had replaced newer drivers with older drivers.

Also, it seems that "INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4" updates the "Intel Chipset Family Driver" and the "INTEL - System - 10.1.14.8" updates the "Intel PCI Bridge". So I think these two updates won't cause any conflicts or problems. (The "INTEL - System - 10.1.14.8" update history can be seen **[here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=intel%20PCI%20BRIDGE)**)

The only thing I did was restoring the previous version of the driver of the "Intel Corporation - Display" (newer version), because the "Intel Corporation - Display - 30.0.100.9805" version that I installed today was actually older (but thankfully the option to "roll back" to the previous driver was available on the Device Manager).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).